# External SSD or HD. Performance compare to internal SSD?

Tags: macbook-pro, storage

I have MacBook Pro 2015 with 128 SSD and want to have some extra storage.

The possible solutions I know are (all external): HDD, SSD, Flash.

Are there any information about the performance of using any of the solutions comparing to my **internal** SSD?

Comment: I'm confused... are you trying to find something that's as fast as your external storage? Have you thought about using an SD card slot storage expander? Have you thought about buying an upgrade for your internal drive? OWC and EBay are good places to look for internal and external drive upgrades. Please give us more details as to what you're looking for.

Comment: @NoahL 128 GB is not too much for me. Thats why I want some extra storage. I don't want to update internal SSD. The rest SD card, HDD etc. I wanted to have some information about these solutions. How fast they are. Something like speed comparison, but not from 2010.

Comment: @NoahL - Post it as answer please and I will ask some extra information in comments.  Thanks.

Comment: Except for boot times, HDD is fast enough for ... just about anything one does.   So, put OS onto the flash, offload videos/books/pix-of-kitties to an external HD (fast-ish) or external portable/laptop HD (medium speed), or networked disk (medium speed), or cloud (medium-to-slow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An external HDD is going to be ~100 MB/s, an external SSD closer to ~500MB/s, the SD card expanders (such as tardisk or transcend jetdrive) have read/write speeds only slightly slower than that of the HDD (~75MB/s). However, the SD expander has the advantage of not actually being external (it sits flush to the edge of the MBP and occupies the SD card spot). Your internal SSD likely has speeds close to ~700MB/s. Network attached storage will only be as fast as your connection. If you have an "N" network, your speed will max out at ~35MB/s, with an "AC" connection or gigabit Ethernet you should have no problem getting full ~100MB/s speeds.

Comment: External HDD - not a WLAN one?

Comment: And how fast is my internal SSD?

Comment: Aslo question - how much speed do I need to work properly with an extra OS (for example Windows) on external drive? Or to use some IDE (Visual Studio, Eclipse)?

Comment: An external HDD via thunderbolt or USB 3 should be plenty of speed, but SSDs aren't super expensive, so it might be worth shelling out a bit extra for one.

Comment: The internal SSD has speeds of about 2GB/s

Comment: @SkeletonBow is that on the 2015 MBP w/ 128GB? I know that my 2014 MBP w/ 256GB SSD had max read/write of ~600MB/s, but heard that the new 2016 TB MBP has read/write speeds of closer to 2GB/s, but the new MBPs have new versions of SSDs

Comment: Oops... well, I meant the write speeds. On Apple's website it says read and write for the 2016 TB MPB are 3.1 and 2.1GB/s respectively. It's 100% faster, meaning that the read speeds for the 2015 model were at ~2GB/s. Quite impressive!